# Событие при добавлении элемента на форму

Tags: javascript, html

Какое событие возникает у объекта при добавлении его на форму?

```
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.className = "error_h transparent";
    h1.innerText = "Открыта другая вкладка";
    var s = document.getElementById('splash');
    s.appendChild(h1);
    s.children[3].classList.remove("transparent");
```

Этот код срабатывает топорно (без анимации при удалении класса transparent) потому что в момент удаления класса объекта еще не было на форме.

Есть ли событие (прим. onappend), чтобы следующий код имел смысл:

```
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.className = "error_h transparent";
    h1.innerText = "Открыта другая вкладка";
    h1.onappend = function () { this.classList.remove('transparent') }
    var s = document.getElementById('splash');
    s.appendChild(h1);
```

Comment: у элемента _который_ вставляется такого события нет. Есть что-то подобное у контейнера, но возможно проще всего использовать setTimeout

Comment: @Grundy ну согласись, setTimeout это костыль... Но если вообще нет никаких других вариантов, то прийдется использовать его.

Comment: почему костыль? если нужно _отложить_ снятие класса, почему не воспользоваться стандартным средством для откладывания? :)